# Spring Slueth implementation for Apache Kafka Producer and Consumer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am not using Spring-Kafka module to produce and consume messages. Instead, I am using Apache client library with producer and consumer implementations. As I am not using Spring-Kafka, the Spring Slueth auto configuration is not applied to generate the traces. I have referred https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/integrations.html I don't find any document around how to apply Spring Slueth for the code which uses 3rd party libraries?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Spring, then don't add it to non-Spring code.

The traces in Sleuth are implemented using [Brave Kafka Interceptor](https://github.com/openzipkin-contrib/brave-kafka-interceptor)